# Problem with downloading .mp3/webm format music/videos from youtube using python youtube_dl

Tags: python, cmd, mp3, youtube-dl, webm

So, it's not my code I found it on youtube tutorial(which I can't find now).

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl
import os
from sys import argv

# Download data and config

download_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': '%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192',
    }],
}

# Song Directory
if not os.path.exists('Songs'):
    os.mkdir('Songs')
else:
    os.chdir('Songs')

# Download Songs
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(download_options) as dl:
    with open('..\\' + argv[1], 'r') as f:
        for song_url in f:
            dl.download([song_url])
```

It is first downloading ".webm" file(video),then converting to mp3 correctly and after that removing original ".webm" video, I don't want it to remove it, when I run it in CMD it says "Deleting original file .webm (pass -k to keep), but I don't know where to pass -k
(I'm not programmer I just copied the code)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass an additional argument

this is copied from youtube_dl github

```
--postprocessor-args ARGS        Give these arguments to the postprocessor
-k, --keep-video                 Keep the video file on disk after the post-
                                 processing; the video is erased by default
```

you can look [here](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/3e4cedf9e8cd3157df2457df7274d0c842421945/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L137-L312) for how to pass the options

I've tested this syntax and it works for me (Darude Sandstorm)

```
   download_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': '%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'keepvideo': True,
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192'
    }]
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work 
`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ngval\Python\downloader.py", line 27, in <module>
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(download_options) as dl:
  File "C:\Users\ngval\Python\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 426, in __init__
    pp_class = get_postprocessor(pp_def_raw['key'])
  File "C:\Users\ngval\Python\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\postprocessor\__init__.py", line 22, in get_postprocessor
    return globals()[key + 'PP']
KeyError: 'keep-videoPP'
`
This is what I get

Comment: my syntax was wrong, I fixed it and linked the resource (github code) i used to figure it out.